# Java: read 2 files and compare line by line

Tags: java, while-loop, readfile, writefile

I'm trying to compare two files line by line. Let's say for example:

File1

```
a,b,c,d,12
e,f,g,h,20
h,g,t,y,30
```

File2

```
f,g,h,j,30
e,h,j,f,50
a,b,c,d,60
e,f,g,h,70
```

I want my output to be like:

```
a,b,c,d,12,50
e,f,g,h,20,70
```

I've written this code:

```
while ((line1 = bufferedFormattedReaderMaster.readLine()) != null) {

    temp1 = line1.substring(0, 7);
    temp3 = line1.substring(8, 10);

    while ((line2 = bufferedFormattedReaderAnalytical.readLine()) != null) {

        temp2 = line2.substring(0, 7);
        temp4 = line2.substring(8, 10);

        if (temp1.equals(temp2)) {

            System.out.println("OH YES");
            bufferedWriterFinalResults.write(temp1 + ","  +temp3 + "," + temp4);
            bufferedWriterFinalResults.newLine();
            numberOfFinalResults++;

        }   
    }
}
```

But my output is only:

```
a,b,c,d,12,50
```

and not the next line.

Comment: What you want to do exactly?

Comment: Gentle reminder that SO is not a place to get your homework done.

Comment: So I want my output to be:

Comment: Hey, it's not for homework. I'm doing a research project with my professor and I've written this code a few days ago. I tried to debug the loops but it doesn't make sense. Is there something wrong with the way I defined my while loop?

Comment: Hint: You need to reset your inner loop to start reading at the beginning of the second file again once you have compared all lines with the first line of the first file.

Comment: quickest solution is just before second `while` line2 do read your file2... `BufferedReader bufferedFormattedReaderAnalytical = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file-2.txt")); `

Comment: and no, your output is wrong... you should get `a,b,c,d,12,60` .. 60 not 50. ;)

Comment: good practice is to .close() your readers too.

Comment: sorry yes 60! thanks

Comment: @MrSimpleMind thanks a lot! it worked =D

Answer (score 0):

The bufferedFormattedReaderMaster and  bufferedFormattedReaderAnalytical can be read only one time. Brush up your skills on I/O. I did a simple list based conversion of your code. The code may not compile but this roughly what you have to implement. There are better ways as well.

```
List<String> bufferedFormattedReaderMasterList =new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> bufferedFormattedReaderAnalyticalList =new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((line1 = bufferedFormattedReaderMaster.readLine()) != null) {

                   bufferedFormattedReaderMasterList.add(line1 );
                }


    while ((line2 = bufferedFormattedReaderAnalytical.readLine()) != null) {

                   bufferedFormattedReaderAnalyticalList.add(line2);
                }



for(String line1:bufferedFormattedReaderMasterList) {

                    temp1 = line1.substring(0, 7);
                    temp3 = line1.substring(8, 10);

                    for(String line2:bufferedFormattedReaderAnalyticalList) {

                        temp2 = line2.substring(0, 7);
                        temp4 = line2.substring(8, 10);

                        if (temp1.equals(temp2)) {

                            System.out.println("OH YES");
                            bufferedWriterFinalResults.write(temp1 + ","  +temp3 + "," + temp4);
                            bufferedWriterFinalResults.newLine();
                            numberOfFinalResults++;

                        }   
                    }
                }
```